# jQuery hide div only if not hovered

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a popout menu and have run into a little issue I'm hoping someone can help with. The menu pops on hover and clicking outside the popup closes it. That's all working fine.

My issue is setting the div to display on hover and automatically hide after X seconds UNLESS the user hovers inside the box inside the time. This would mean the popup would conceal itself unless needed.

Could anyone advise? I know it'll involve setTimeout and clearTimeout but I'm unsure as to how to apply them in context.

The code I have at the moment is as follows:

```
$('.links #links-schools a').bind('hover mouseenter', function() {

  var school     = $(this).text();

  $('.links #links-schools a').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("current-menu-item");
  });

  if(school == "Introduction") {

    $('.sublinks ul').hide();
    $('.links #links-schools ul').removeClass('right-border');

  } else {

    $(this).addClass("current-menu-item");

    var str        = $(this).parent().attr('class').slice(-3);
    var editedstr  = str.replace(/\D/g,"");

    $('.links #links-schools ul').addClass("right-border");
    $('.sublinks ul').hide();
    $('.sublinks img').show();
    $('.sublinks').show();

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.bbdclients.com/sac-active-wp/buildnav.php",
      type: "POST", 
      data: { parentschoolid: editedstr },
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(data) { 

        if (data.toLowerCase().indexOf("home") >= 0 || data.length < 1) {
          $('.sublinks img').hide();
          $('.sublinks ul').hide();
          return false;
        }
        else {
          $('.sublinks ul').html(data);
          $('.sublinks img').hide();
          $('.sublinks ul').show();
        }
      }
    });

  }

  return false;   
});
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
$('.links #links-schools a').bind('hover mouseenter', function() {
    var idTimeout;

    // your code

    idTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#div-to-hide').hide();
    }, 5000);

    $('#div-to-hide').on('mouseenter', function() {
        clearTimeout(idTimeout);
    });
});
```

Give it a try and let me know about any doubts.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm having trouble implementing this code - the div still opens ok but the timeout doesn't seem to trigger? (I updated the #div-to-hide correctly, incidentally.

Comment: Do you still have a problem with the code? If you do, please tell me. If you don't, please accept it as the answer. :)

Comment: It worked a charm, thank you! I'm unsure as to how to accept it as the answer? If I'm being daft and not seeing the option let me know and I'll update it :)

Comment: You got it.. Glad that helped! :)